# Fit an image in a fixed height row with css grid

Tags: css, image, grid

I have a fixed width and height container which I'm trying to fill an image and some text. I'd like to have the text "drawn" first then have the image fit in the rest of the container. Here's an image of what I'm after:

[Example Image Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64D43.jpg)

Seems like this should work however the image doesn't respect the height of the row its in:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  gap: 40px;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href='somelink' class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/07/16/47/kingfisher-2046453_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Test</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I dont uderstand your question well. Do you wish the text first or second? 

 If I would follow the image, there is problem with size of the picture. If you need picture to be 500px width, it will be 332px height. You dont have enough pixels to place the image itself. Where will be the text?

Comment: Text should be underneath the the image. I want my image to sized down such that the text and the image fits within the 500 x 300 rectangle.

Comment: Here's an example of what I would like to accomplish. https://codepen.io/KevinGutowski/pen/XWevmKy

Hover when I swap out the div with the `.image` class with an image element, the image pushes the text down outside the frame of the container. I don't want this. I want the image to be sized down to fit the `fr` region.

Comment: Oki, there is only difference between your example and codepen - you forgot to write down   `height: 100%;` - than the size of the image will atomaticly be the rest size of the grid. There will be the gap 40px.

Comment: Not quite, it won't take the size of the row but rather 100% of its parent. I need the image and the text to fit within the fixed height of the container. I can't have the text overflowing out. https://codepen.io/KevinGutowski/pen/XWevmKy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure it out! Looks like you need to wrap the image in a div AND be sure to specify `overflow:hidden`. For some reason, that will ensure that the image gets resized down and isn't just scaling up to fit within the parent.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  gap: 40px;
}

.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

img {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href='somelink' class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/07/16/47/kingfisher-2046453_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <span>Test</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, see below.
I guess your text overflowed, because you set the height of text 40px and than inserted long text.
Check also [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) - nice property to manage the part of picture you want to see if `object-fit: cover;`

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  gap: 40px;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
 <a href='somelink' class="container">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/07/16/47/kingfisher-2046453_960_720.jpg" alt="">
   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Nulla est. Maecenas sollicitudin. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Nullam faucibus mi quis velit. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. Aliquam id dolor. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam. 
   </span>
</a>
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  background-color: limegreen;
  gap: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right top;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/07/16/47/kingfisher-2046453_960_720.jpg" alt="">
  <span>Some text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Nulla est. Maecenas sollicitudin. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Nullam faucibus mi quis velit. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. Aliquam id dolor. Sed ac dolor sit amet purus malesuada congue. Etiam dui sem, fermentum vitae, sagittis id, malesuada in, quam. </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help! I appreciate it. I want both the image and the text to be inside the container, it shouldn't overflow. The image shouldn't push down the text.

Here you can see the image and the text overflowing from the grid container
[Example Inspector](https://i.imgur.com/YqgG0dz.png)

Here's the behavior I'm looking for. I want to have the image to shrink down to fit inside the leftover space
[Example behavior](https://i.imgur.com/AtdrcA7.jpg)

Comment: @kevski I am sure, it is in the first snippet I post here.. it shrinked  the imige and when I test it from the dev tool inspector.. it has exactly 500x300.

Comment: If you see the first snippet different, let me know.. I am really curious about it now..